# Bootstrap modal is loaded even when form is not valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal like this:

```
<a href="#summaryModal" onclick="return generate_summary()" data-toggle="modal" style="color:white"><button type="submit" id="summarize_btn" class="btn btn-success offset3">Summarize</a></button>

<div id="summaryModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Summary</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    <textarea disabled id="summary_output" name="summary_input" rows="15" class="span5"></textarea> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Summarize Again</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My generate function is like this:

```
function generate_summary() {
    var summary_input=document.getElementById('summary_input').value;
    var email_notify=document.getElementById('email_notify').value;
    var num_sent=document.getElementById('num_sent').value;
    if(summary_input=='' || num_sent==''){
    alert('Input text or specify the number of sentences!');    
    return false;
    }
    else {
      $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/summary/",
                data: {summary_input:summary_input, email_notify:email_notify, num_sent:num_sent},
                success: function(data){
                     $('#modal-body').html(data)
               return true;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

When the form is invalid I don't want the modal to popup. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You have an `<a>` link (with the onclick) wrapped around a `<button>` which seems redundant (and the closing tags are backwards).

First, simplify that line with:

```
<button type="button" id="summarize_btn" class="btn btn-success offset3">Summarize</button>
```

Now, using jQuery, bind to the click of that button and only show the modal upon the success of the ajax callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#summarize_btn").bind('click', function(){
        var summary = $("#summary_input").val();
        var num_sent = $("#num_sent").val();
        if (summary == '' || num_sent == '') {
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/summary/",
            data: $("#form_id").serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                 $('#modal-body').html(data);
                 $('#summaryModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Many aspects of JavaScript are **asynchronous**, meaning that a function can be called somewhere, start a process that takes some time (e.g., an AJAX request), but the first function doesn't wait for it to finish and return a value. This is the reason for **callbacks**, which are functions passed as arguments to other functions, which are then called when a certain event happens.

In this case, when you use jQuery's `ajax` method, you specify a callback for "success" and for "error". But for all intents and purposes these callbacks don't know that they're part of the generate_summary function. jQuery just knows to execute the `success` callback when the request finishes successfully, and the `error` callback if the request finishes with an error.

Thus, if you return a value in the `success` callback, that value doesn't get propagated all the way up to `generate_summary`. `generate_summary` has already been run and has long since finished running without returning a value. What you need to do here is specify a callback that opens the modal if the AJAX request is successful. Or, in this case, you need to wait until the AJAX request is finished AND successful before you open up the modal. So you should first take the `data-toggle` property of your button, so it doesn't toggle the modal on click. Again, you only want to toggle the modal if the request is successful, and that needs to be checked only when the request is completed.

Something like this would do it:

```
function generate_summary() {
    var summary_input=document.getElementById('summary_input').value;
    var email_notify=document.getElementById('email_notify').value;
    var num_sent=document.getElementById('num_sent').value;
    if(summary_input=='' || num_sent==''){
        alert('Input text or specify the number of sentences!');    
        return false;
    }
    else {
      $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/summary/",
            data: {summary_input:summary_input, email_notify:email_notify, num_sent:num_sent},
            success: function(data){
                 $('#modal-body').html(data)
                 $('#summaryModal').modal('show');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to be a pedant but... JavaScript is Synchronous. It emulates Asynchronous behavior but only ever executes on a single thread. You're right that **A** JAX calls work this way but you may be misleading newbies into think all functions do the same...

Comment: You're right, thanks. Changed my answer to be less confusing. I didn't know JS runs on only one thread, I always figured that every time you had an AJAX method or some other "asynchronous" method that it just opened another thread. How does it do all this on one thread?

EDIT: Found a good article here: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: +1 - And yeah it caught me by surprise the first time I discovered it was single-threaded. Nice explanation link